# Alternate update form in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to make a form that you can only access once before a certain boolean is set to true, and along with it you input some other info, the problem is that I don't know how to set it up properly, so far the form loads no problem, but it doesn't update the information of the user.

my main problem is that I don't know how to set up the routes and the form, since most of the time I just use `resources:` to make them automatically

here is my form :

```
<%= form_for @user, url: organizer_user_path, method: :put do |f| %>
.
.
.
<%end%>
```

my routes, which I don't think put is correct at all

```
get 'organizer/user', to: "users#organizer_form"
put 'organizer/user', to: "users#organizer_registration"
```

and my controller

```
def organizer_form
@user = User.find(current_user[:id])
end

def organizer_registration
  @user = User.find(current_user[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'organizer_form'
  end
end
```

I'm sure the problem lies in how I define my routes and how they are called onto the form, any help?

here are the params that are submitted:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  _method: put
  authenticity_token: w9zTUQLK+4kZtbvRCfcYfZgn8ma4xSRdbTMy+fktpoHlGADxHSB6u9QBh3K3zv72V/Ys2b3Q1MiKC0Gr+OqNJw==
  user: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
    parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      organizer: 'true'
      contact_name: Name
      last_name: Last name
      contact_email: mail1@mail.com
      cellphone: '1234567'
      company: ''
      office_phone: ''
      website: ''
    permitted: false
  commit: continuar
  controller: users
  action: organizer_registration
permitted: false
```

This is my `user_params`

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :organizer, :contact_name, :last_name, :contact_email, :cellphone, :company, :office_phone, :website)
end
```

Comment: Can you post the `params` generated on form submit?

Comment: I posted the params, I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the `put` and `patch` methods.

Comment: Add your `user_params` method

Comment: added my `user_params` method.

Comment: Do you got any validations in the model? Do you see any rollback in log?

Comment: the only validations I have are for name, password and e-mail, none of which are handled by my current form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148841/discussion-between-pavan-and-bluespheal).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer!  I had

```
attr_accessor :organizer, :contact_name, :last_name, :contact_email, :cellphone, :company, :office_phone, :website
```

which somehow stopped the update from happening, so removing that made the updates save to the database.